# come a long way

Tags: word-usage, phrase-meaning

I understand the phrase "come a long way" to mean to make a lot of improvement, but in this context, what does it mean?

> 69' The hosts are putting a bit of pressure on. Another deep free-kick, swung into the danger area - Lumley **comes a long way** to make a firm punch.
> Stoppage in play - Hutchinson clattered in the melee and needs a bit of treatment.
> #MILREA | 0-1

[Reading FC](https://twitter.com/ReadingFC/status/1563550396194234370?s=08)

Comment: In the context of a field game, it might mean he traveled a longer than usual distance to do whatever making a punch is. Without a video of the game, it might be hard to unravel what was meant.

Comment: @JackO'Flaherty Thank you. Does it mean to rise highest in this context?

Comment: I don't know for sure, as I don't follow sports. However, it seems to put the "punch" after "come a long way", so it might mean that he personally moved across the field. Your questions seem to be about sports jargon, more than about standard English.